# Можно ли поставить в БСП запятую вместо тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение, бсп

*Представь свою страницу в соцсетях без аватарки, резюме без фото — это то же самое.*

По идее вместо запятой должно стоять тире, но, т.к. тире уже есть во втором предложении, можно ли поставить запятую? Простые предложения не связаны отношениями перечисления (одновременности и последовательности) — между простыми предложениями нельзя вставить союз и. Также предикативные части бессоюзного сложного предложениия не близки между собой по смыслу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не очень понятен, грамматика фразы неоднозначна (Jasmin, видимо, трактует по-своему, я распространения во второй части не вижу). Спрошу так: на основании какого правила вы хотите тире на месте, где стоит запятая?

Если на основании этого, то опускать тире нельзя.

> 3. Тире ставится, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения 
>      содержит следствие, результат, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой
>      части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда и т. п.):

Розенталь Д.Э., Справочник по пунктуации.

Здесь, правда, спорно само отнесение к подобному случаю, является ли вторая часть выводом из первой?!

Но Вот из другого розенталевского же источника:

> 3. Тире ставится, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения содержит следствие, результат, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой
>      части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда и т. п.): Я
>      умираю — мне не к чему лгать (Т.); Вы раздвинете мокрый куст — вас так
>      и обдаст накопившимся тёплым запахом ночи (Т.); Не было никакой
>      возможности уйти незаметно — он вышел открыто, будто идёт на двор, и
>      шмыгнул в огород (Ф.); Я бы в летчики пошёл — пусть меня научат (М.);
>      Достав из кармана одновременно и спички, и зажигалку, Крайнев зажёг
>      шнуры — они вспыхнули (Поп.); Наше жильё — нам и беречь; Ставят
>      самовар в сенцах — запах дыма разносится вокруг; За ночь все отдохнули
>      — можно снова приниматься за прерванную работу; Ключ потерян — ломайте
>      дверь.

https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/48854/66/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html

Хотя формально наш пример не совсем попадает под формулировку, нет подходящего слова для вставки, приводятся очень близкие примеры - из Маяковского особенно.

Теперь с другой стороны.
Формально правила, **предписывающего** избавляться от второго тире, не существует. Существует некая корректорско-редакторская рекомендация делать это в тех случаях, когда иное мешает восприятию структуры. Точно так же нет никаких правил **обязывающих** заменять в подобных случаях тире на запятую.
Хотя это вполне можно сделать, если это не противоречит смыслу.

Таким образом, решение вопроса - за автором. Если ему важно подчеркнуть, что вторая часть именно следствие, вывод из первой, то два тире можно оставить. Правда, ничто не мешает и саму фразу перестроить так, чтобы восприятие улучшилось.

***Представь свою страницу в соцсетях без аватарки — это то же самое, что резюме без фото.***

Пожалуй, этот компромисс - лучшее, что можно рекомендовать.

Но если автор не видит во второй части следствия из первой, то следуем примечанию у Розенталя.

> 1. Если значение следствия интонационно не подчеркивается, то вместо тире ставится запятая: …Я допрошу его осторожно, он и не заметит (Ч.);
>      Человек не иголка, найдём (Ч.).

(там же)

Таким образом, вариант с запятой тоже возможен. Но он, признаться, куда менее понятен.

Comment: Два тире точно лучше не ставить: сразу видится вставная конструкция или приложение.

Comment: Тут скорее не следствие/результат/вывод, а просто присоединение. Можно, действительно, использовать примечание и поставить запятую.

Answer (score 1):

**Тире не подойдет, только запятая.**

Это БСП **неоднородного** состава, вторая часть **распространяет** содержание первой.

Интонация нисходящая с полным понижением тона в конце первой части (похоже на два отдельных предложения, только без длительной паузы).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил точку или точку с запятой.

**Представь свою страницу в соцсетях без аватарки. Резюме без фото — это то же самое.**

Или изменить фразу.

**Представь свою страницу в соцсетях без аватарки. Это как резюме без фото.**

Comment: Эти предложения тесно связаны — не хочется разделять их без веской на то причины.